# Cache dynamic page on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, razor

I have a dynamic internal status page for the team written in ASP.NET/Razor and hosted on IIS. The page queries multiple services and sql databases to generate the dynamic content.

I was wondering what would be the various ways to cache the page content on the above setup so the page doesn't have to query the various services it uses whenever a user loads the page and instead it fetches the content every few minutes. (all users see the same content/page)

Edit: The website is written using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using at least .Net 4.0, you want to use caching.

Since you don't list the language you're using, the best I know of is to point you here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Ff477235(v=VS.100).aspx

If you're using c# (or are good at translating c# into another .Net language) this example is really good:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: I am guessing I will have to set up a cache for each component/call (ideally) and then have a updatecallback associated which would refresh the cache after a period of time.. I was wondering if there's something out there which might make the process easier, like https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/ for wordpress.

Comment: If you look at the second link above, you'll see how to wrap caching around a controller's method.  Pretty straightforward.  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Just to add more the 2nd link was exactly what I wanted... Also to force a refresh I created a new action which did: HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/Controller/Action"); return RedirectToAction("Action");