# Asynchronously refresh Cached dynamic pages in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, asynchronous

As a followup to the question here:

> [Cache dynamic page on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317737/cache-dynamic-page-on-server-side)

I was wondering if there was a way to asynchronously refresh the outputcache over time, say start the async refresh 2 minutes after instead of the cache expiring at 3 minutes and then have a user visit re-cache the page.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking at Invalidating OutputCache?
You could use RemoveOutputCacheItem method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681136.aspx

Comment: Not exactly, invalidating the cache causes the outputcache to get new content on the next page reload, What I want to Get new content asynchronously when the cache is about to expire so the content is cached and available for all page loads

Comment: Fire an HTTP call to the web page you want to catch after you invalidate the cache?

Comment: Well, I only force invalidate the cache sometimes, how would I handle the automatic cache expiry, is there a call back that I can register (or that happens) when the cache expires?

Comment: Since you are the one "force" invalidating the cache, you should not need a callback as you know exactly when you are invalidating the cache. So in your logic - invalidate the cache - then fire the HTTP call.

Comment: Not always, the cache is also set to expire every 3 mins. How can I handle that case?